# I need help for animation in flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

I wanted to know if it is possible to replicate this in Flutter, I know of the existence of Heroes but I know that they are only applicable with images.
What would be the best solution?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnnUZ.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is replicable in Flutter.
Hero doesn't need to wrap only images you can experiment with any element for some really cool animation effects.
Consider reading this - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations